# Submodular function. Why this name?

Tags: algorithms, terminology

Today I came across the definition of a [submodular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function). I was wondering why it is called like this.

Answer (score 2):

Submodularity of a function $f:2^N\rightarrow \Bbb R$ for $N=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$ means
$$
f(S)+f(T)\ge f(S\cap T)+f(S\cup T)
$$
for all subsets $S,T$ of $N$. It is called *supermodular* if the equality is the other way around, and *modular* if there is equality, i.e., both submodular and supermodular.

So the question is where the name "modular" here comes from. It reminds me on [modular lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice).

Also Arthur's explanation is good, however the name "modular function" reminds me very much on [modular forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form), which is something different.